# Python: replacing multiple words in a text file from a dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, replace, text-files

I am having trouble figuring out where I'm going wrong.  So I need to randomly replace words and re-write them to the text file, until it no longer makes sense to anyone else.  I chose some words just to test it, and have written the following code which is not currently working:

```
# A program to read a file and replace words until it is no longer understandable

word_replacement = {'Python':'Silly Snake', 'programming':'snake charming', 'system':'table', 'systems':'tables', 'language':'spell', 'languages':'spells', 'code':'snake', 'interpreter':'charmer'}

main = open("INF108.txt", 'r+')

words = main.read().split()

main.close()

for x in word_replacement:    
    for y in words:
        if word_replacement[x][0]==y:
            y==x[1]

text = " ".join(words)

print text

new_main = open("INF108.txt", 'w')
new_main.write(text)
new_main.close()
```

This is the text in the file:

> Python is a widely used general-purpose, high-level programming 
>   language. It's design philosophy emphasizes code readability, and  its
>   syntax allows programmers to express concepts in fewer lines  of code
>   than would be possible in languages such as C++ or Java.  The language
>   provides constructs intended to enable clear  programs on both a small
>   and large scale.Python supports multiple  programming paradigms,
>   including object-oriented, imperative and  functional programming or
>   procedural styles. It features a  dynamic type system and automatic
>   memory management and has a  large and comprehensive standard
>   library.Python interpreters are  available for installation on many
>   operating systems, allowing  Python code execution on a wide variety
>   of systems. Using third- party tools, such as Py2exe or Pyinstaller,
>   Python code can be  packaged into stand-alone executable programs for
>   some of the  most popular operating systems, allowing for the
>   distribution of  Python-based software for use on those environments
>   without  requiring the installation of a Python interpreter.

I've tried a few methods of this but as someone new to Python it's been a matter of guessing, and the last two days spent researching it online, but most of the answers I've found are either far too complicated for me to understand, or are specific to that person's code and don't help me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**OK**, let's take this step by step.

```
main = open("INF108.txt", 'r+')
words = main.read().split()
main.close()
```

Better to use the [`with`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) statement here. Also, `r` is the default mode. Thus:

```
with open("INF108.txt") as main:
    words = main.read().split()
```

Using `with` will make `main.close()` get called automatically for you when this block ends; you should do the same for the file write at the end as well.

---

Now for the main bit:

```
for x in word_replacement:    
    for y in words:
        if word_replacement[x][0]==y:
            y==x[1]
```

This little section has *several* misconceptions packed into it:

1. Iterating over a dictionary (`for x in word_replacement`) gives you its *keys* only. Thus, when you want to compare later on, you should just be checking `if word_replacement[x] == y`. Doing a `[0]` on that just gives you the first *letter* of the replacement.
2. Iterating over the dictionary is defeating the purpose of having a dictionary in the first place. Just loop over the words you want to replace, and *check* if they're in the dictionary using `y in word_replacement`.
3. `y == x[1]` is wrong in **two** ways. First of all, you probably meant to be *assigning* to `y` there, not *comparing* (i.e. `y = x[1]` -- note the single `=` sign). Second, assigning to a loop variable doesn't even do what you want. `y` will just get overwritten with a new value next time around the loop, and the `words` data will NOT get changed at all.

---

What you want to do is create a *new* list of possibly-replaced words, like so:

```
replaced = []
for y in words:
    if y in word_replacement:
        replaced.append(word_replacement[y])
    else:
        replaced.append(y)
text = ' '.join(replaced)
```

Now let's do some refinement. Dictionaries have a handy [`get`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) method that lets you get a value if the key is present, or a default if it's not. If we just use *the word itself* as a default, we get a nifty reduction:

```
replaced = []
for y in words:
    replacement = word_replacement.get(y, y)
    replaced.append(replacement)
text = ' '.join(replaced)
```

Which you can just turn into a one-line [list-comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
text = ' '.join(word_replacement.get(y, y) for y in words)
```

And now we're done.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want something like this as your if statement in the nested loops:

```
if x==y:
    y=word_replacement[x]
```

When you loop over a dictionary, you get its keys, not key-value pairs:

```
>>> mydict={'Python':'Silly Snake', 'programming':'snake charming', 'system':'table'}
>>> for i in mydict:
...    print i
Python
programming
system
```

You can then get the value with `mydict[i]`.

This doesn't quite work, though, because assigning to `y` doesn't change that element of `words`. You can loop over its indices instead of elements to assign to the current element:

```
for x in word_replacement:    
    for y in range(len(words)):
        if x==words[y]:
            words[y]=word_replacement[x]
```

I'm using [`range()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range) and [`len()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#len) here to get a list of indices of `words` (`[0, 1, 2, ...]`)

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is probably here:

```
if word_replacement[x][0]==y:
```

Here's a small example of what is actually happening, which is probably not what you intended:

```
w = {"Hello": "World", "Python": "Awesome"}
print w["Hello"]
print w["Hello"][0]
```

Which should result in:

```
"World"
"W"
```

You should be able to figure out how to correct the code from here.

Comment: I knew I was doing something wrong... calling on the wrong thing.

Answer (score 0):

You used `word_replacement` (which is a dictionary) in a wrong way. You should change for loop to something like this:

```
for y in words:
    if y in word_replacement:
        words[words.index(y)] = word_replacement[y]
```