# Normalization on a corpus using a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, normalization, corpus

I want to do lexical normalization on a corpus using a dictionary. The corpus has eight thousands of lines and the dictionary has thousands of word pairs (nonstandard : standard).

I have adopted an approach which is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30008163/python-replacing-multiple-words-in-a-text-file-from-a-dictionary). The code looks like this:

```
with open("corpus.txt", 'r', encoding='utf8') as main:
    words = main.read().split()

lexnorm = {'nonstandard1': 'standard1', 'nonstandard2': 'standard2', 'nonstandard3': 'standard3', and so on}

for x in lexnorm:
    for y in words:
        if lexnorm[x][0] == y:
            y == x[1]

text = ' '.join(lexnorm.get(y, y) for y in words)

print(text)
```

The code above works well, but I'm facing a problem since there are thousands of word pairs in the dictionary. Is it possible to represent the dictionary through a text file?

Last question, the output file of the code consists only of one line. It would be great if it has the same number of lines as the original corpus does.

Anyone could help me with this? I'd be thankful.

Comment: Your code could not possibly work well. First of all, `y == x[1]` is not an assignment and even if it were `y = x[1]` you would not be modifying anything in `words` and if you were, you would only be assigning a single letter. Are you trying to replace whole words `y` in `words` by looking them up in `lexnorm` and substituting `lexnorm[y]` for `y`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to output the dictionary as a text file is as a `JSON` string:

```
import json

lexnorm = {'nonstandard1': 'standard1', 'nonstandard2': 'standard2', 'nonstandard3': 'standard3'} # etc.

with open('lexnorm.txt', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(lexnorm, f)
```

See my comment to your original. I am only guessing what you are trying to do:

```
import json, re

with open('lexnorm.txt') as f:
    lexnorm = json.load(f) # read back lexnorm dictionary

with open("corpus.txt", 'r', encoding='utf8') as main, open('new_corpus.txt', 'w') as new_main:
    for line in main:
        words = re.split(r'[^a-zA-z]+', line)
        for word in words:
            if word in lexnorm:
                line = line.replace(word, lexnorm[word])
        new_main.write(line)
```

The above program reads in the `corpus.txt` file line by line and attempts to intelligently split the line into words. Splitting on a single space is not adequate. Consider the following sentence:

```
'"The fox\'s foot grazed the sleeping dog, waking it."'
```

A standard split on a single space yields:

```
['"The', "fox's", 'foot', 'grazed', 'the', 'sleeping', 'dog,', 'waking', 'it."']
```

You would never be able to match `The`, `fox`, `dog` nor `it`.

There are several ways to handle it. I am splitting on one or more non-alpha characters. This may need to be "tweeked" if the words in `lexnorm` consist of characters other than a-z:

```
re.split(r'[^a-zA-z]+',  '"The fox\'s foot grazed the sleeping dog, waking it."')
```

Yields:

```
['', 'The', 'fox', 's', 'foot', 'grazed', 'the', 'sleeping', 'dog', 'waking', 'it', '']
```

Once the line is split into words, each word is looked up in the `lexnorm` dictionary and if found then a simple replace of that word is done in the original line. Finally, the line and any replacements done to that line are written out to a new file. You can then delete the old file and rename the new file.

Think about how you might handle words that would match if they had been converted to lower case first.

**Update (Major Optimization)**

Since there is likely to be a lot of duplicate words in a file, an optimization is to process each unique word once, which can be done if the file is not so large that it cannot be read into memory:

```
import json, re

with open('lexnorm.txt') as f:
    lexnorm = json.load(f) # read back lexnorm dictionary

with open("corpus.txt", 'r', encoding='utf8') as main:
    text = main.read()
word_set = set(re.split(r'[^a-zA-z]+', text))
for word in word_set:
    if word in lexnorm:
        text = text.replace(word, lexnorm[word])
with open("corpus.txt", 'w', encoding='utf8') as main:
    main.write(text)
```

Here the entire file is read into `text`, split into words and then the words are added to a set `word_set` guaranteeing the uniqueness of words. Then each word in `word_set` is looked up and replaced in the entire text and the entire text rewritten back out to the original file.